# Angular front end not making rest call to Flask Application

Tags: javascript, angular, rest

I have a flask application running in this  url http://127.0.0.1:5000/SectionA
I am returning the data in json format using return jsonify(data).When I hit the url from the browser it looks like this

[image]

I am calling this url from the angular application main-service.ts file like  this

```
 public getVamData(id,section): Observable<any> {
         try {
         console.log("I am here getVAM");
         return this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/SectionA')
                .map((response: Response) => {
                    console.log("I am here getVAM2");
                    return response.json();
                }
            );
           }
        catch(e) {
        console.log('Error:', e);
        }   }
```

But the url is not hitting the flask application. Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: ... and where do you subscribe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to subscribe the Observable because Observable are lazy loaded.
and if you are using getVamData() method of service in somewhere else(like components) then subscribe there.
use like this

```
this.mainService.getVamData(this.paramData.Eid,'SectionA')
.subscribe(result=>{
  this.data=result;
console.log(this.data);
})
```

Comment: I am subscribing it in vam_component.ts file                                        constructor(public route:ActivatedRoute,public      mainService:MainServiceService) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.paramData=params;
        console.log(this.paramData)
        this.data=this.mainService.getVamData(this.paramData.Eid,'SectionA');
        console.log(this.data);

Comment: I made the changes but still not able to access it. I have 2 applications django running in port 8080 and flask in 5000. I am able to call django rest api url but not able to call flask api url. Should I make some changes in configuration file to access both the applications running on different ports?

Comment: I have moved the flask application part in to Django rest frame work and now I am getting response in main-service.ts but I am getting data as undefined in the `this.mainService.getVamData(this.paramData.Eid,'SectionA').subscribe(result =>{ 
        this.data=result;
        console.log(this.data);
        }, error => console.log(error));`

Comment: Now I am getting response but subscribe runs recursively. I want to store my json response in a variable after one round of iteration and work on that that json data something like `var temp=this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/vamcomponent/')` please explain me how to do that.

Comment: this.data=result; this line is storing response's data in data property variable do whatever you want to do with this data. Please accept my answer if your initial problem is solved

Comment: How can I read that json reponse? I want to do find the details under classes object in json structure?I tried using `console.log(this.data._body);` and `console.log(this.data.classes);` but both are coming as **undefined**.

Comment: what are you getting in console.log(this.data) or console.log(result) inside subscribe ?

Comment: I am getting json response from getVamData() which receives Httpresponse from API.

Comment: ```(2) ["1", {…}]
0: "1"
1:
classes: Array(1)
0:
class: "SectionA"
details: (11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Comment: I need some thing like loop over the classes to fetch the data inside details. `this.data.classes` doesn't work.

Comment: let classes=this.data[1].classes; because your response data is array and classes is the name of the field at index 1.now use classes variable to loop and let me it is working for you are not

Comment: The code is working as expected :) Thanks for the help.